# Why does $| \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0} - g'(x_0)| \le \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$ imply $| \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0}| \ge \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Why does $\left| \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0} - g'(x_0)\right| \le \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$ imply $\left| \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0}\right| \ge \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$ ?

In a proof of l'Hospitals rule we let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ be an open interval, $x_0 \in I$ and $f,g$ be differentiable in $x_0$. Suppose $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$ and $g'(x_0) \neq 0$.

We start by showing there exist $[x_0-r, x_0+r] \subseteq I$, where $r>0$, such that $g(x) \neq 0$ $\forall x\in [x_0-r, x_0+r] \setminus \{x_0\}$.

Let $\epsilon = \frac{|g'(x_0)|}{2}$ then there exist $\delta >0$ such that $0<|x-x_0| \le \delta $ imply $$\left| \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0} - g'(x_0)\right| \le \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$$

However I don't know how to prove the inequality in question. I've tried using the triangle inequality: $\left|\frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0}\right| - |g'(x_0)|\le \left|\left| \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0}\right| - |g'(x_0)|\right|\le \left| \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0} - g'(x_0)\right|\le \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$

Answer (score 2):

I believe its because you replaced $g'$ with $g$ by accident: you let $ε = \frac{|g'(x_0)|}{2}$ but then use $ε =  \frac{|g(x_0)|}{2}$ in the next line. What you want is

$$\left|\frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x-x_0} - g'(x_0)\right| \leq \frac{|g'(x_0)|}{2}$$

And from this you can prove your inequality using almost exactly what you tried.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that I've done a typo. I guess my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$ | |\frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0}| - |g^{'}(x_0)||\le | \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0} - g^{'}(x_0)|\le \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$$

by using the triangle inequlity for complex numbers $\mathbb C$.

Thus $$ -\frac {|g(x_0)|} 2 \le|\frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0}| - |g^{'}(x_0)|\le \frac {|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$$

which imply

$$ \frac {|g(x_0)|} 2 \le|\frac {g(x)-g(x_0)} {x-x_0}| \le \frac {3|g^{'}(x_0)|} 2$$